# How to "run" Blender 2.8 in 18.04

Tags: executable, execute-command, blender

In the install instructions, they say "run" the Blender executable for v 2.8. While I have the executable in the extracted folder, I don't know which command will "run" it. I tried `run blender` within the folder without success. Would be great if someone can help me out.

[image: blender.svg in file manager window]

Edit 1 :

[image: file properties]

Edit 2:

```
$ ./blender
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   167
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   167
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   167
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   167
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   167
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   167
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   GLXBadFBConfig
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Received X11 Error:
    error code:   8
    request code: 152
    minor code:   34
    error text:   BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
found bundled python: /home/dell/Downloads/blender-2.80-linux-glibc217-x86_64/2.80/python
```

Comment: @pomsky the file " blender" is already executable.

Comment: I don't know how to run it. Install instructions say " Linux: Unpack the archive, then run the Blender executable.  "

Comment: Did you see the accepted answer to the duplicate I suggested? "*You can then execute it like this:* `./filename.sh`". So what happens if you then run `./blender` in the directory?

Comment: I saw the link proposed answer. Please see the edit in the original question. I think I have to run the executable, not a .sh file. At least that is what the install instructions say.

Comment: Please see the output of ./blender as Edit 2 in the original question. I got a blank window.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't tell anything, it's not clear whether it's *allowed to execute*. You need to check the *Permissions* tab. Also `.sh` means nothing, in general suffixes mean nothing in GNU/Linux world. Only thing matters is whether it's an executable file or not.

Comment: Ok. Looks like when we wait enough `./blender` command works. Thank you.